# Auto-detect Jinja2 files and activate proper highlighting in Sublime Text

Tags: python, sublimetext2, jinja2

Right now I have the package Jinja2 installed and it gives proper syntax highlighting, but I have to change the syntax every time I open a new html file.

I would like Jinja2 highlighting to be the default for html in Python projects. The only solution I came up with so far was to change all Jinja files to `.jinja` instead of `.html` and then I could create a separate `Jinja.sublime-settings`, but I'm not quite sure this won't give me problems later and I would prefer not to tweak very much.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot set per-project file-extension-to-syntax associations in Sublime.

Comment: Essentially, using a dedicated extension is the only way to do this at the moment, really.

Answer (score 4):

From the comment by @Martijn Pieters it seems indeed that I need a dedicated extension. I looked more into this and found out something that may be a good alternative.

The [Jinja2 package](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Jinja2) highlight Jinja2 HTML files with a syntax called `HTML (Jinja Templates)`. I can create a configuration file (must be called `HTML (Jinja Templates).sublime-settings`) for this extension in the `Packages/User` folder and include the following lines there:

```
{
    "extensions":
    [
        "jinja.html"
    ]
}
```

In this case, I just need to rename my `html` files to `jinja.html` and they will be highlighted as soon as loaded. And I keep the html extension, just in case.

I am borrowing the idea from the Rails world. When using HAML they name their files `filename.haml.html`.